# How to create pd.MultiIndex for existing pd.DataFrame object, using Pandas and Python 3?

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, dataframe, multi-index

I'm looking for something equivalent to `pd.read_table(path/to/file, index_col=[0,1])` for an existing `pd.DataFrame`.

I frequently encounter `pd.DataFrames` that have the following format:

```
# Index Data
iters = 3*[1] + 3*[2] + 3*[3]
clusters = 3*[1,2,3]

# Recreate DataFrame
DF_A = pd.DataFrame([iters, clusters], index = ["iteration", "cluster"]).T
DF_B = pd.DataFrame(np.random.RandomState(0).normal(size=(100,9)), index = ["attr_%d"%_ for _ in range(100)]).T
DF_concat = pd.concat([DF_A, DF_B], axis=1).set_index("iteration", drop=True)
DF_concat.head()
```

[image]

If I loaded these into `Python`, I would just do `index_col=[0,1]` like I described above but how can I convert a prexisting `pd.DataFrame` `pd.Index` into  a `pd.MultiIndex` so `iteration` is the outer index level and `cluster` is the inner index level?

I tried the following but the assignments got messed up.  There should only be 3 per iteration for the simple example I made:

```
DF_B.index = pd.MultiIndex(levels=[DF_concat["cluster"].index.tolist(), DF_concat["cluster"].tolist()], labels=[DF_concat["cluster"].index.tolist(), DF_concat["cluster"].tolist()], names=["iteration", "cluster"])
DF_B
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this..

```
DF_concat.set_index([DF_concat.index, 'cluster'])
```

Comment: I didn't know you could called the index while you're setting it.  Thanks!